# Unknown Source when try to load image

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to load an image in my desktop app but i don't know the route of the image

Error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(Unknown Source)     at
>   ventanas.Success.(Success.java:30)

Code:

```
Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("checked.png")).getImage();
```

My project tree:

[image]

I am try the next routes:

"checked.png"

"/checked.png"

"img/checked.png"

"/img/checked.png"

pd: img is a "Source Folder"

Comment: Verify that the `img` folder is been included in the class path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `img` folder is not in the Build Path.

The little package symbol in the folder icon indicates that.
Press <kbd>Right Mouse</kbd> on  the `img` Folder, select `Build Path` and click `Use as Source Folder`

If for some reason it still is not in the Build path click `Configure Build Path...` and add it manually.

Comment: thanks, this happened when I clone the project from git repository.